# Force intellij to download scala-library sources in an existing project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

It seems that Intellij does well when "Download sources" and "Download javadocs" are checked in the import settings.

But if they were *not* checked then how do we get the scala sources after the fact?  In the screenshot below I did click on `Download Sources`

[image]

But it failed `Sources for 'scala-library.jar' not found`  .

[image]

Seems Intellij should realize to properly ornament the `scala-library.jar` with the appropriate scala version from the project . no?

So is there any alternative to simply nuking the project and re-importing? The reason for the inquiry is I have a number of projects in this state and also would like the flexibility to *not* always have `Download sources` checked - due to both longer build time and occasional build failures caused by it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can edit the sbt settings of an existing project:

[image]
[image]

After selecting 'Download: Sources' and closing the settings, you must refresh the sbt project to trigger the download:

[image]

Comment: 5 years later and this was driving me crazy. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another option to attach the sources, if Intellij is not downloading it automatically, is to download from the Scala page manually and attach in Intellij.

Example:

- Go to https://www.scala-lang.org/download/2.13.1.html
- Download the sources in the link (e.g. [scala-sources-2.13.1.tar.gz](https://github.com/scala/scala/archive/v2.13.1.tar.gz))
- Extract the zip file
- In Intellij, click on the *Attach Sources* (as in the screenshot on the question)
- Inform the path where the file was extracted